# Listelement with different alignment than others

Tags: html, css, list, nav

I have a navigation-bar based on a list.
Looking like that:

[image]

I'm wondering how i can get the Logout listpoint on the right site of the screen. I already tried it by adding clear listitems but thats just a dirty workaround and don't work for every screen-resolution.

My list looks like that:

```
<ul runat="server" id="tabs">
   <li class="test">
   <a href="DetailView.aspx?call=104"><span class="tab">  
      <strong>EnterData</strong></span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="test">
     <a href="Overview.aspx"><span class="tab">
     <strong>Overview</strong></span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="test">
     <a href="Logout.aspx"><span class="tab">
     <strong style="text-align: right">Logout</strong></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My Question is: Am I able to get this item right? If this doesn't work with a list, I would be glad to see a way for a diffenrent solutions.
I hope I was able to display my problem understandable.
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a float on the list item to place logout on the right of the header, I used last child but you can create another class or place it inline on the li:

```
.test:last-child{
    float:right;
}
```

Text align would also work on the li, however you would need to specify the width of the li to get it to look right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<li class="test" style="text-align: right">
 <a href="Logout.aspx"><span class="tab"><strong>Logout</strong></span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That doesn't work. No matter where i put it, in the list item or in the css-part of the list. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Have a look to the Brooke's answer just above. It is a better and nicer way to do what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You must align the whole list item. It's not hard; just add some new class, like `floatRight`.

```
 <ul runat="server" id="tabs">
       <li class="test">
       <a href="DetailView.aspx?call=104"><span class="tab">  
          <strong>EnterData</strong></span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="test">
         <a href="Overview.aspx"><span class="tab">
         <strong>Overview</strong></span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="test floatRight">
         <a href="Logout.aspx"><span class="tab">
         <strong style="text-align: right">Logout</strong></span></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

And the css:

```
.floatRight{float:right;}
```

You could style it inline too, if you really want to: `<li class="test" style="float:right;">`

Comment: Brooke Bennett's answer is fine, even better too.